# Is there always only one unique shortest path between any two nodes in a Kautz di-graph ? If yes, why ? If no, why not?

Tags: graph-theory

My intuition tells me that there is always a unique, single shortest path between any two nodes in a [Kautz di-graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kautz_graph). Is this true ? If yes, why? If not, why not ?

My intuition is based on the fact that Kautz graphs are best known optimal degree-diameter [digraphs](http://combinatoricswiki.org/wiki/The_Degree_Diameter_Problem_for_General_Digraphs), that is, for a given degree (d>2) and diameter the Kautz graphs are the largest known graphs. So in this sense, one could argue that Kautz graphs do not "waste" shortest path connections.

Answer (score 1):

For two nodes labeled $w_1$ and $w_2$ there will always be a *largest* $n$ such that the last $n$ symbols in $w_1$ are the same as the first $n$ symbols in $w_2$. The unique shortest path from $w_1$ to $w_2$ then arises by shifting in the *rest* of the symbols in $w_2$ one by one -- clearly doing anything else will just send us on a detour.

In the particular case that $n=0$ we just need to check that we're *allowed* to start by shifting in the first symbol of $w_2$ -- but the only reason we *wouldn't* be would be if the first symbol of $w_2$ is the same as the last symbol of $w_1$, and then $n$ would be at least $1$.

Comment: Many thanks Henning, I will sit down and think this over ... next to a nice cup of tee during the weekend.